# Open MPI Eclipse PTP -> failed to execute command: ompi_info ,

Tags: eclipse, programming, mpi

I try to compile parallel programs using Open MPI 3.1 with Eclipse PTP 9.1.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.

After building the project I follow the instructions of the [Help-Eclipse Platform](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Frms%2FopenMPI.html).

The Step *Run Configurations → Parallel Application → [project name] → Target System Configuration → Generic OpenMPI Interactive*
works fine, but if I specify the *Connection Type* to *Local* I get the following error message.

```
failed to execute command: ompi_info -a --parseable reason: cannot run program "ompi_info" (in directory "/home/name/Downloads/eclipse"): error=2, No such file or directory`
```

The [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Parallel_Tools_Platform_FAQ#Q%3a_I_get_the_error_.22Failed_to_execute_command%3a_ompi_info_-a_--parseable.22_when_I_use_the_Open_MPI_target_configuration_on_my_Mac) suggests that the required command cannot be found in my PATH environment variable because eclipse may use different ones. 
I tried adding my `$PATH` and my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` into the environment variables *Run Configurations → [project name] → Environment*, I also tried starting eclipse from a shell.

I reinstalled Ubuntu and Open MPI several times.

EDIT//
 I installed it using [this](http://lsi.ugr.es/jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf) Guide. I tried both ways (quick and manually), both times the same error occured.

I now just installed mpich and it works fine.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to describe *how exactly* you installed OpenMPI and how configured Eclipse or the project to use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should install `openmpi-bin` package which provides [*/usr/bin/ompi_info*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=ompi_info) executable with:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin
```